# Fundamental understanding of SPARQL

Tags: sparql, dbpedia

I try to understand SPARQL and mess around with the SPARQL Tool that is provided by [dbpedia](http://dbpedia.org/sparql). I've read the [w3](https://www.w3.org/TR/2013/REC-sparql11-query-20130321/) documentation and now I want to create my very own query. I would like to find the names of all books in dbpedia written by J. J. R. Tolkien.

Therefore I "designed" this query:

```
    SELECT ?name WHERE { ?name ?author "J._R._R._Tolkien".
                         ?name ?mediaType "Print"}
```

The result is empty, but I would at least expect this book popping up:
http://dbpedia.org/page/The_Lord_of_the_Rings

Can someone tell me, what my conceptual mistake is?

Comment: First, I would suggest reading something about RDF, in particular the principle of 'subject - predicate - object' and resources, literals and so on. Secondly, once you understand the basics of RDF – and SPARQL is a query language for RDF-based data – you will see that you would need a predicate for the relation "written by", you need to figure out the direction of this relation in the dataset you're working on, and usually it'S more efficient to use the resource URI of "J._R._R._Tolkien"

Comment: I'm brand new to SPARQL, and found this to be very helpful https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t1Mn178sEYg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I good approach would be to review his DBpedia page and then choose the desired properties. In your case two good candidates are  `notableWork` and `author`. Here's a query with both of them, effectively using the latter.

```
PREFIX : <http://dbpedia.org/resource/>
PREFIX o: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>
PREFIX p: <http://dbpedia.org/property/>

SELECT DISTINCT  ?is_author_of #?has_notable_work
FROM <http://dbpedia.org/>
WHERE {
:J._R._R._Tolkien rdf:type o:Writer ;
#o:notableWork ?has_notable_work ;
^p:author ?is_author_of .
}
```

I have used `rdf:type o:Writer` to reduce possible ambiguity (none, in case of using URI of an individual resource in dbpedia), and `^` to get the right direction. My preference for `?is_author_of`  and `?has_notable_work`instead of e.g. `?book` and `?popular_book` was because I'm not sure what kind of work is he author of.

Comment: How should `rdf:type o:Writer` reduce any ambiguity when you're using a resource URI, which in fact is a unique identifier. For me this is totally unclear and a redundant triple pattern.

Comment: In this case it is redundant indeed. But as it is rare to point directly to an individual resource, I put it for the sake of the good habit with the understanding the the actual query would rather use REGEX or some other way which would permit ambiguity, and using Tolkien is just a temporary test. But thank you, I have modified my answer to reflect this.